# Help me understanding this statement

Tags: probability, definition, finance

Specifically, for each price vector $p$ in the finite set $P$, we define $\pi(p)$ as the time average fraction of time that $p(t) = p$, so that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\sum_{\tau=0}^{t-1}1\{p(\tau)=p\}=\pi(p) \quad\text{ with probability 1}$$
where $1\{p(\tau)-p\}$ is an indicator function that is $1$ if $p(\tau)=p$, and zero otherwise.

This excerpt was taken from "M. J. Neely. Stock market trading via stochastic network optimization. ArXiv Technical Report, arXiv:0909.3891v1, Sept. 2009."

Comment: for simplicity, suppose $0\leq j<t$ denotes the $j$-th month. Over a period of $t$ months (measured the firs day of each month) the number of times the monthly price $p(j)$ of a certain product has value $p$ is $\sum^{t-1}_{j=0}\mathbb{1}(p(j)=p)$. Hence, in average, the amount of time the price for this product stays at the price of $p$ is $\pi_t(p)=\frac{1}{t}\sum^{t-1}_{j=0}\mathbb{1}(p(j) =p)$. The conclusion is the laws of large numbers (although the assumptions on $p(j)$ are not given).